# PHP Session not working no matter what - However other website works

Tags: php, session

Basically just making some back-end for my portfolio, in pretty early days right now so the code is messy and a lot of playing around still.

I had sessions working but now they're not.

My website is set up like so: portfolio, then sub folder for my back end. It contains an index.php (which I log in through) then its supposed to load dashboard.php and pass in the session (which should pass in that im logged in) then load all of the dashboard.

However it loads "You are not logged in" the weird thing is.. if i purposely type in an incorrect password on the index.php, it STILL loads dashboard.php and says "you are not logged in" instead of just echoing "please try again"

My index.php: http://pastebin.com/eCzxUCkY
Dashboard.php: http://pastebin.com/waJ2HAXA

Thought it may be neater to post them there instead.

Please help :( I've restarted my pc, cleared my cache, done everything. It won't work locally, and it wont work on my host. HOWEVER i do have another site running all the same stuff and it still works. So i feel like its something in my actual code :(

Comment: Then why are you not shared the code?

Comment: I have - I posted both my files in the pastebin links as I think its cleaner to view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I added some extra error checking.

On your log in page replace this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["username_login"])) {
    $username = $_SESSION["username_login"];
    $loggedIn = true;
}
```

with this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["username_login"]) && $_SESSION["username_login"] != '') { // does the session exist and if so, does it have a value
    $username = $_SESSION["username_login"];
    $loggedIn = true;
} else {
    $_SESSION['username_login'] = NULL; // empty the session value
    unset($_SESSION['username_login']); // kill the session
    $loggedIn = false;
}
```

On your dashboard, replace this

```
<?php
session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION["username_login"];
    $loggedin = true;
}
?>
```

with this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["username_login"]) && $_SESSION["username_login"] != '') { // does the session exist and if so, does it have a value
        $username = $_SESSION["username_login"];
        $loggedin = true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['username_login'] = NULL; // empty the session value
        unset($_SESSION['username_login']); // kill the session
        $loggedin = false;
    }
?>
```

`session_destroy()` does not "kill" a session. It's equivalent to `$_SESSION['something'] = ''`. The session is still alive, it's just empty.

To completely kill a session you have to "unset" it.

**References**

[session_destroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

[unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Comment: I added your code but it doesn't fix the error :( still can't log in at all :(

Comment: Place this just above the line `// User login` on your login page. Load the page and let's see what you get. `if($loggedIn) { echo 'logged in<br>'; } else { echo 'NOT LOGGED IN<br>'; } // what's the value of logged in` Then next line `echo 'username: '.$username.'<br>';` Just some troubleshooting. I start echo-ing and die-ing my page in steps to find out what the heck is going on.

Comment: Curious... why the `LIMIT 1` in your query? There should only be 1 user with that exact set of credentials.

Comment: It says "NOT LOGGED IN" Then next line is "username: ". Do you have skype or something? It may be easier to quickly be able to talk about what I should do. I've tried echoing and stuff but really can't figure out what I've done to screw it all up..

Comment: I got that from a tutorial, I'm also not sure why it's there, but it hasn't caused problems so I've never bothered to remove it

Comment: I almost had it fixed. I think I may be close to the issue.

Comment: I actually fixed it. Weird issue. It seems the redirect to dashboard was too quick maybe? So it wasnt getting time to start/store the session? So i just did an alternative way to redirect to dashboard and now it works fine.. Not sure why this happened when I changed nothing...

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I always do two things when I'm using sessions:

1) Set a session name using the PHP function:

```
session_name('myAppName');
session_start();
```

2) If the user login fails, I destroy the session:

```
session_destroy();
```

so it removes whatever could be stuck inside the session info.

Have you tried it?

Comment: I have session_destroy() for my logout.php, I also tried adding it to the failed login, and also added a session name, but neither fix my problem :(

Comment: Like I noted in the OP. No matter if the username/password is correct, or wrong, it still sends me to the dashboard (when it should only do this when its correct) :( it's definitely not an error in my database.

Answer (score 0):

```
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION["username_login"];
    $loggedin = true;
}
```

You have a misplaced closing brace in your `dashboard.php`. Are you using an IDE, or a text editor? Most IDEs will highlight syntax errors. It took me less than a few seconds to find that once I pasted your code into Netbeans.

I'm guessing you copy/pasted this code from your `index.php`, and didn't remove one of the curly braces. Easy mistake to make. A decent IDE will spot that immediately.

Comment: Ah, complete didn't notice that brace :(. I'm using sublime text, but sadly removing that brace doesn't fix the issue.